# Android executable with wrong interpreter?

Tags: android, android-ndk, toolchain

i've moved to new laptop and latest android NDK, recompiled the binaries into my android app and got "executable not found" exception while running. I've checked the file exists and is on expected path.

Then i've analyzed the file and got the following:

```
$file ./build_pie/my_file
./build_pie/my_file: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /usr/lib/libc.so.1, not stripped
```

Then i've checked the previous version of the executable and it was:

```
$file /tmp/f4_old/my_file
/tmp/f4_old/my_file: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /system/bin/linker, not stripped
```

I believe wrong interpreter is the reason. How can i fix it?

PS.

Here are some lines from config:

```
... // override PATH and SYSROOT to android NDK (standalone toolchain)

export CFLAGS="-I$SRC/libftdi1.0-2-android-arm-lollipop/include -I$SRC/libusb1.0-2-android-arm-lollipop/include -fPIE"
export CPPLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -fPIE"
export CXXLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -fPIE"
export LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -lusb-1.0 -lusb -lftdi -L$SRC/libftdi1.0-2-android-arm-lollipop/lib -L$SRC/libusb1.0-2-android-arm-lollipop/lib -L$SRC/libusb-android-arm-lollipop/lib -static -fPIE -pie"

../configure --build=x86-unknown-linux-gnu --host=arm-linux-androideabi --target=arm-linux-androideabi --verbose
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to specify dynamic linker with `-Wl,--dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker` (add to `LDFLAGS`)

Answer (score -1):

Based on your answer, you've done all the effort of assembling a cross compiler for use with autoconf yourself. You should take a look at [standalone toolchains](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html), the tool the NDK ships to save you from these kinds of mistakes.

Comment: that's exactly what i used

Comment: Ah, okay. Had no way to infer that from your question. You shouldn't need to manually specify the linker path when you use a standalone toolchain. It might be that the project you're building is explicitly setting it to the wrong path for you? Somewhere in autoconf or the makefile? You've worked around it so maybe you don't care; just trying to make sure you're not tripping over an actual bug.