# segfault before main() is called in cross-compiled armhf

Tags: gcc, raspberry-pi, linker, arm, cross-compiling

I've finally cross-compiled and linked a binary on an Ubuntu Xenial x86_64 host to run on the Raspberry Pi 4's armhf.

My toolchain's from [ARM](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads) and placed in `$TOOLCHAIN`.

My sysroot is a loop-mounted [Raspberry OS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/) image placed in `$RASPBIAN_ROOT`.

This is a sample compilation line:

```
$TOOLCHAIN/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -std=c++11 --sysroot=$RASPBIAN_ROOT \
  -D_ARM_ -DOTHER_DEFINES \
  -v -w -fexceptions -fpermissive -pipe \
  -mcpu=cortex-a72 -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard \
  -Wabi-tag -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 \
  -fno-use-cxa-atexit \
  -g \
  -I . -I .. -I extlib1/include -I extlib2/include -I $RASPBIAN_ROOT/usr/include/libxml2 \
  -I $TOOLCHAIN/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include \
  -I $RASPBIAN_ROOT/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf \
  -I $RASPBIAN_ROOT/usr/include \
  -c File.cpp -o obj/linux/armhf/debug/File.o
```

There are also some `.c` files. And this is the linking line:

```
$TOOLCHAIN/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld.gold \
-L ../localdependency \
-L $RASPBIAN_ROOT/opt/vc/lib \
-L $RASPBIAN_ROOT/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf \
-L $RASPBIAN_ROOT/lib \
-L$RASPBIAN_ROOT/usr/lib \
-L $RASPBIAN_ROOT/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8 -o bin/linux/armhf/debug/executable obj/linux/armhf/debug/File.o ... \
$RASPBIAN_ROOT/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/crtbegin.o \
$RASPBIAN_ROOT/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/crtend.o \
$RASPBIAN_ROOT/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/libgcc_eh.a \
--verbose --sysroot=$RASPBIAN_ROOT \
-lbcm_host -lvcos -lvchiq_arm -lcurl -lxml2 \
-lpthread -lz -lm -ldl -lstdc++ -lc -lgcc -lgcc_s
```

...which seems to produce an executable. (Both lines edited for readability.)

However, when running on the pi, i get a segfault:

```
$ ./executable param1 param2
Segmentation fault
```

If i try to debug, it's not even reaching `main()`:

```
$ gdb executable
GNU gdb (Raspbian 8.2.1-2) 8.2.1

...

(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x2c7c74: file main.cpp, line 7029.
(gdb) r param1 param2
Starting program: /home/user/executable param1 param2
warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will be unable to debug shared library initializers
and track explicitly loaded dynamic code.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb6f97420 in __libc_enable_asynccancel () at ../nptl/cancellation.c:33
33  ../nptl/cancellation.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb6f97420 in __libc_enable_asynccancel () at ../nptl/cancellation.c:33
#1  0xb6f77968 in __GI___libc_write (nbytes=407, buf=0xb6fdc838 <banner>, fd=1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/write.c:26
#2  __GI___libc_write (fd=fd@entry=1, buf=0xb6fdc838 <banner>, nbytes=nbytes@entry=407) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/write.c:24
#3  0xb6ec98d8 in __libc_print_version () at version.c:71
#4  __libc_main () at version.c:71
#5  0x00000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb)
```

While i see the "warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function." (and am trying to figure out where in the packages does ld.so come from) i'm more inclined to believe my toolchain/sysroot/libs is not properly configured.

A simple helloWorld cross-compiles and executes fine:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i = 1;
    std::cout << "hello world " << i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ ./rpihello 
hello world 1

$ ldd rpihello 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0xbef33000)
    /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-${PLATFORM}.so => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v7l.so (0xb6f90000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb6e30000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0xb6dae000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6d81000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6c33000)
    /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6fa5000)
```

---

**Edit 1**

Since `nptl/cancellation.c` seems to come from libc, i double-checked i had all the necessary packages, and i believe i do (otherwise i'd be having widespread problems with the Pi):

```
pi$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/\*
/opt/vc/lib
# Multiarch support
/usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfakeroot
# libc default configuration
/usr/local/lib

pi$ apt list --installed | grep ^libc
libc-ares2/now 1.14.0-1 armhf [installed,upgradable to: 1.14.0-1+deb10u1]
libc-bin/stable,now 2.28-10+rpi1 armhf [installed]
libc-dev-bin/stable,now 2.28-10+rpi1 armhf [installed,automatic]
libc-l10n/stable,now 2.28-10+rpi1 all [installed,automatic]
libc6-dbg/stable,now 2.28-10+rpi1 armhf [installed]
libc6-dev/stable,now 2.28-10+rpi1 armhf [installed]
libc6-pic/stable,now 2.28-10+rpi1 armhf [installed]
libc6/stable,now 2.28-10+rpi1 armhf [installed]
libcc1-0/stable,now 8.3.0-6+rpi1 armhf [installed,automatic]

pi$ apt list --installed | grep ^libgcc
libgcc-6-dev/stable,now 6.5.0-1+rpi1+b1 armhf [installed,automatic]
libgcc-8-dev/stable,now 8.3.0-6+rpi1 armhf [installed,automatic]
libgcc1-dbg/stable,now 1:8.3.0-6+rpi1 armhf [installed,automatic]
libgcc1/stable,now 1:8.3.0-6+rpi1 armhf [installed]
```

So i still think i borked the cross-compilation/linking somehow.

---

**Edit 2**

I've managed to compile my codebase on the raspberry pi and the produced binary exhibits the same results as the cross-compiled one. So either i've misscompiled or i have both my sysroot and the pi's system a bit borked.

---

**Edit 3**

```
rpi $ readelf -dW myexecutable

Dynamic section at offset 0x664e58 contains 48 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x00000003 (PLTGOT)                     0x6716d4
 0x00000002 (PLTRELSZ)                   5856 (bytes)
 0x00000017 (JMPREL)                     0x2d940
 0x00000014 (PLTREL)                     REL
 0x00000011 (REL)                        0x2d2e0
 0x00000012 (RELSZ)                      1632 (bytes)
 0x00000013 (RELENT)                     8 (bytes)
 0x00000015 (DEBUG)                      0x0
 0x00000006 (SYMTAB)                     0x8148
 0x0000000b (SYMENT)                     16 (bytes)
 0x00000005 (STRTAB)                     0xfb48
 0x0000000a (STRSZ)                      94185 (bytes)
 0x6ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)                   0x26b34
 0x00000004 (HASH)                       0x2930c
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libbcm_host.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libvcos.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libvchiq_arm.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libjson.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libmylocallib.so]
...
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libz.so.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libdl.so.2]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x00000019 (INIT_ARRAY)                 0x66dd60
 0x0000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)               244 (bytes)
 0x0000001a (FINI_ARRAY)                 0x66de54
 0x0000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)               4 (bytes)
 0x6ffffff0 (VERSYM)                     0x2c1b0
 0x6ffffffe (VERNEED)                    0x2d0f0
 0x6fffffff (VERNEEDNUM)                 9
 0x00000000 (NULL)                       0x0
```

I found this interesting:

```
rpi $ file myexecutable
myexecutable: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /usr/lib/libc.so.1, with debug_info, not stripped
rpi $ file `which ls`
/bin/ls: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=67a394390830ea3ab4e83b5811c66fea9784ee69, stripped
```

Shouldn't my executable be using ld as the interpreter?

---

**Edit 4**

I [added](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42975061/1831722)[[2]](https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/processors/b/processors-ip-blog/posts/file-not-found-when-executing-assembled-program) `--dynamic-linker=/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3` to my linker line, but now i get no stack:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

Running `strace executable` the last lines are these:

```
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, ~[ILL TRAP BUS FPE KILL SEGV STOP RTMIN RT_1], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGILL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0xb5e55120}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE, {tv_sec=6336, tv_nsec=768744979}) = 0
gettimeofday({tv_sec=1631533208, tv_usec=497816}, NULL) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\314\4bJn\36\16\240f\203\216I\257\306\251r\202\v\232\263\210\374\222\276TN\33,[\3A\233", 32) = 32
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\301\231\203~G6Ey_\262Y\241\34\216F\2448w\2365Z\213\376\223\260\322zwo\334+e", 32) = 32
close(3)                                = 0
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=NULL} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
Segmentation fault
```

`/dev/urandom` does exist though.

---

**Edit 5**

```
$ readelf -h executable
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x0
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          40514564 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000400, Version5 EABI, hard-float ABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         8
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         37
  Section header string table index: 36
```

I don't think entry point address should be 0x0.

---

**Edit 6**

I've compiled the code on a pi3 and on an arm-qemu chroot - same result.

Comment: What's the output of `readelf -dW executable`? (You may have to use the cross-tool version of `readelf`.)

Comment: @FlorianWeimer i ran `readelf` on the pi instead. I find the interpreter difference curious.

Comment: Moving from cross compile to native-build is good. I would expect you're using different build command/options, maybe add those in an edit? You are showing 10x more options than I have ever found necessary.

Also tell us what OS you have (e.g. Raspbian or what? 32 or 64 bits?), when you're doing native-build.

Note, if your executable (or some subset) can be built with your OS's stock gcc, without a custom sysroot, and maybe statically linked e.g. 
gcc File.cpp -o File.o ; ./File.o
That could get you in a working direction, good luck.

Comment: @JoeKul it's not practical to natively compile using Raspbian buster on a raspberry pi (trying to support all). I'm trying to setup an armhf chroot in my development x86_64 Ubuntu Xenial VM instead. Preliminary tests look promissing.

Comment: Did you try to use toolchain from https://sourceforge.net/projects/raspberry-pi-cross-compilers/files/Raspberry%20Pi%20GCC%20Cross-Compiler%20Toolchains/Buster/GCC%2010.2.0/Raspberry%20Pi%203A%2B%2C%203B%2B%2C%204/cross-gcc-10.2.0-pi_3%2B.tar.gz ?

Comment: @mpromonet no, not yet, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to cross-compile with the [toolchain](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools) from raspberrypi.org and set `--sysroot=` to a Raspbian image. Their [releases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi_OS#Release_history) more or less follow Debian's and always support all existing Raspberry Pies.
Both `CXX` and `LD` point to their `g++`, meaning it's GCC who determines linking flags. If necessary I can use `-Wl,..`
Other than `-Wabi-tag -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`, `CFLAGS` is pretty standard.

---

Raspbian changed their download URL format between Buster [10.3](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/raspbian-2020-02-14/) (2020-02-13) and [10.4](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_armhf/images/raspios_lite_armhf-2020-05-28/) (2020-05-28) and started providing full and lite versions. I used the latter.
Since these images typically have almost no free space, I first [extend](https://gist.github.com/jkullick/9b02c2061fbdf4a6c4e8a78f1312a689) the image file, partition (p2) and underlying filesystem, so I can install the `-dev` packages that satisfy the dependencies of my project by chrooting into the sysroot via quemu-arm.